# jquery dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use such code to access item

```
function f(id){

$("#"+id).val(); // with analogy $("#id item")
}
```

is it correct? is any other methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to return the value of an element with specified id, then yes as that is what seems to be logical purpose of your function:

```
function f(id){
  return $("#" + id).val();
}
```

The functions should assume that an element with specified id exists and then it returns you the value of that element. This should work for `input` fields as well as `textarea`. If however, it is any other element, you might want to use `html()` or `text()` instead of `val()` eg:

```
function f(id){
  return $("#" + id).html();
  // return $("#" + id).text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use PureDom

```
function f(id){
   return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

Take that, jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is perfectly valid way to access the element having its id.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery API website:

> **.val() Returns: String, Array**
>
> Description: Get the current value of
> the first element in the set of
> matched elements.

What It's not clear to me when you say

> // with analogy $("#id item")

is if you want to have ONLY one child item of the one that is identifiedby #id or if you need the item that is identified by item#id.

Your code is perfect if you are passing a string like "**hello**" inside your code and you want to get the DOM element with ID of **#hello**.